# Transferring from one activity ( database ) to another activity

Tags: android, listview

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Database extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);

        DatabaseHelper dbh = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        Cursor myCursor = dbh.getReadableDatabase()
                        .rawQuery("SELECT _id, " + DatabaseHelper.NAME +
                                  ", " + DatabaseHelper.VALUE + 
                                  " FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE, null);
        String[] dataFrom = {DatabaseHelper.NAME, DatabaseHelper.VALUE};
        int[] dataTo = {R.id.name, R.id.value};

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                R.layout.row, myCursor, dataFrom, dataTo);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        /*TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Hello, Android");
        setContentView(tv);*/



    }

    public void onListItemClick()
    {

    }



}
```

I am trying to insert a button at the bottom of the Listview to goto another activity. Is it possible to insert a button in this listview ? I need the button to access the next activity which will be a a menu containing options.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you don't just put a button in your XML layout, and put an onClick() method on it that'll do what you want?

Comment: that is because, we do not call r.layout.main in the code , if u noticed , I have commented it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to Add an extra button on the Activity then you have to replace this line--

```
 public class Database extends ListActivity
```

from this line--

```
 public class Database extends Activity
```

and you have to use this line also--

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Because if you want to add extra control then its neccessary to set layout..

Afterthat Simply In your main.xml--

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Next Activity" />

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

In Activity use add this also--

```
ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
lv.setClickable(true);
```

// to set button

```
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent=new Intent(this,NextActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    }
 });
```

And Replace this line--

```
 setListAdapter(adapter);
```

From--

```
 lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I have solved your problem....whereever i told the mistake.... changed it accordingly...

Comment: THANKS A LOT HULK ..what is ur email?

Answer (score 1):

In XML :

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:dividerHeight="1dip" 
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />

<Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Next" />
```

In Activity :

```
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
});
```